# Short cut menu not showing network locations

Tags: windows-10

At some point in the past, my network locations stopped showing up in my desktop shortcut menu.
I've researched the problem but found no solutions.
I did a Windows repair and update to no avail.
I am running Windows 10 on an HP Z600 work station. I've 2 of these computers. The menu works fine on one machine but not this one.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the "desktop shortcut menu"? Adding screenshots of the two computers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut to `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL ncpa.cpl` will show Network Connections CPL.

To test that, press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and paste that into the edit box.

If it *does not* work, repair Windows using [SFC and DISM](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) or reinstall Windows.

If the CPL did appear, then create a new shortcut **in an appropriate place**, such as in `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts`. *Over time, MS has made changes to the locations where shortcuts must be located.*

See [these tips](https://windowsreport.com/windows-8-1-shortcuts-working/) for more help, applicable to Windows 10, as well as 8.1.